# Shrine derivatives plugin method :image_derivatives! error undefined method 'bytesize' for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, shrine

Thank you for any and all help!

I am attempting to create derivatives for an image that is uploaded in a Rails controller action.

To start, I installed `imagemagick` and `vips` with homebrew:

```
brew install imagemagick
brew install vips
```

I have the following in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'shrine', '~> 3.0'
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.8'
gem "aws-sdk-s3", "~> 1.14"
```

In `app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb` I have:

```
require "image_processing/mini_magick"
 
class ImageUploader < Shrine

    plugin :cached_attachment_data
    plugin :determine_mime_type
    # plugin :remove_attachment
    plugin :validation
    plugin :validation_helpers
    plugin :derivatives

    Attacher.validate do
        validate_max_size 100.megabytes, message: 'Attachment is too large'
        validate_mime_type_inclusion [ 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif' ]
    end

    Attacher.derivatives_processor do |original|
        magick = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(original)

        {
            large:  magick.resize_to_limit!(800, 800),
            medium: magick.resize_to_limit!(500, 500),
            small:  magick.resize_to_limit!(300, 300),
        }
    end

end
```

In `app/config/initializers/shrine.rb` I have:

```
require 'shrine'
require 'shrine/storage/s3'

Shrine.plugin :activerecord

s3_options = {
    bucket: Figaro.env.S3_BUCKET,
    region: Figaro.env.S3_REGION,
    access_key_id: Figaro.env.S3_KEY,
    secret_access_key: Figaro.env.S3_SECRET
}

Shrine.storages = {
    cache: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "cache", **s3_options),
    store: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(s3_options)
}
```

In my controller, I have:

```
  def create
    handle_money
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|

      if @product.save
        @product.photo.image_derivatives!
        format.html { redirect_to purchases_products_path, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
      else
        @photo = @product.build_photo
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My models include the Shrine image attachment and setup the associations:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
    include ImageUploader::Attachment(:image)
    belongs_to :product
end
```

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    monetize :price_cents
    has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :photo, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo
end
```

My Rails form is:

```
<%= form_for product, multipart: true do |f| %>
  <% if f.errors.any? %>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/flash_message', locals: { alert_type: 'danger', msg: f.object.errors.full_messages.to_sentence } %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, value: f.object.name&.humanize || nil, required: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.text_field :price, value: f.object.price || nil, required: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :photo do |photo| %>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <%= photo.hidden_field :image, value: photo.object.cached_image_data %>
      <div class='input-group'>
        <div class='custom-file'>
          <%= photo.file_field :image, class: 'custom-file-input' %>
          <label class='custom-file-label' for='inputGroupFile04'>Choose File</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions d-flex align-items-baseline justify-content-between">
    <%= link_to "Back", purchases_products_path(), class: "btn btn-secondary p-2" %>
    <%= form.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary p-2" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My error occurs at the line in the controller:

```
@product.photo.image_derivatives!
```

and the logs show the following:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `bytesize' for #<Array:0x00007ffc826ce518>:
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:37:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:32:in `create'
```

The error may be a result of the imagemagick and vips libraries but I am unsure how to trace the error any further.

The upload works without using the derivatives plugin (and subsequent code related).

I would like to know a solution to this error (clearly), as well as better way to trace these errors (outside of the gem 'pry'). Again, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

That helped me:

https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/issues/492

I've use last version directly from github repo.

Remove current version of Shrine and add this line to Gemfile instead:

`gem 'shrine', github: 'shrinerb/shrine'`

Comment: Hey @Alexwell. This gem version worked. Thank you so much!